# How to prove $\pi ^{3}$ is not constructible from the fact that $\pi $ is not constructible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to do this for $\sqrt[3]{\pi }$: First suppose it is constructible and then you just set it equal to $x_{0}=\sqrt[3]{\pi }$ and take the third power of both sides. Then you get $x^{3}_{0}=\pi $ is constructible, which is a contradiction to the fact. But how do we deal with $\pi ^{3}$? You can't take 3rd square roots and still get a constructible number. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's transcendental?

Comment: What else can we use form $\pi$? It cannot be only from that information since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible but $(\sqrt[3]{2})^3=2$ is.

Comment: Yes. We don't have to prove that. We can directly use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mere fact that $\pi$ is not constructible is insufficient to prove that $\pi^3$ is not constructible. As user139271 points out, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible, yet $2$ is.

You will have to appeal to a stronger property of $\pi$. For example, if we use the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental, then $\pi^3$ is also transcendental (proof: if $\pi^3$ were algebraic then $\sqrt[3]{\pi^3} = \pi$ would be algebraic). Transcendental numbers are not constructible (proof: constructible numbers are formed from the algebraic operations add/subtract/multiply/divide/square root on the numbers 0 and 1, and therefore must be algebraic).